# XAML: disable all elements in container but scroll

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, layout, scroll

I have this devExpress xaml element (but the questin it's general, I think it fits with other no-devExpress cases):

```
<dxlc:LayoutControl Grid.Column="1" Orientation="Vertical" UseLayoutRounding="True" 
                            IsEnabled="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=Window},Path=DataContext.canEditImpianti}" 
                            DataContext="{Binding SelectedItem, ElementName=lst1}" Margin="0,10,0,0">
```

As you can see, I set as enabled/disabled the layoutControl with a binded bool. All the text field inside are corretly disabled when it is necessary, but it also disables the scroll (the fields are a lot and I need a scroll to view them all).

I want to disable all the input, but keeping the scroll feature. How can I do it? I have also tried the IsManipulationEnabled attribute, but it seems it doesn't do anything.

This is how I defined my scrollbar:

```
<ScrollViewer x:Name="scrollViewer" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" Width="Auto" Height="Auto">
```

Obviously, the container is inside the scrollViewer tags. How can I solve my issue?

this is my xaml:

```
<ScrollViewer x:Name="scrollViewer" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" Width="Auto" Height="Auto">
    <Grid  x:Name="ext" Height="336">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition />
            <ColumnDefinition/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="37"  />
                <RowDefinition  />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <dxe:SearchControl x:Name="searchControl" FilterCondition="Contains" FilterByColumnsMode="Custom" Margin="10,0" >
                <dxe:SearchControl.ColumnProvider>
                    <dxe:SelectorEditColumnProvider>
                        <dxe:SelectorEditColumnProvider.CustomColumns>
                            <sys:String>CODICE</sys:String>
                            <sys:String>NOME</sys:String>
                        </dxe:SelectorEditColumnProvider.CustomColumns>
                    </dxe:SelectorEditColumnProvider>
                </dxe:SearchControl.ColumnProvider>
            </dxe:SearchControl>

            <DockPanel Grid.Row="1" Margin="0,60,0,0">

                <dxg:GridControl x:Name="lst1" ItemsSource="{Binding ListaImpianti}"  EnableSmartColumnsGeneration="True" 
                    FilterCriteria="{Binding FilterCriteria, ElementName=searchControl}"  MaxHeight="500" Height="266" 
                                 VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="0,-27,0,0" ShowBorder="False" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedTabImpianti}">
                    <dxg:GridControl.Columns>
                        <dxg:GridColumn x:Name="CODICE" Binding="{Binding CODICE}" FieldName="{DynamicResource ResourceKey=Codice}"/>
                        <dxg:GridColumn x:Name="NOME" Binding="{Binding NOME}" FieldName="{DynamicResource ResourceKey=Nome}"/>

                    </dxg:GridControl.Columns>
                    <dxg:GridControl.View>
                        <dxg:TableView AllowPerPixelScrolling="True" AllowEditing="False" ShowGroupPanel="False" ShowFilterPanelMode="Never"  />
                    </dxg:GridControl.View>
                </dxg:GridControl>
            </DockPanel>
        </Grid>

        <dxlc:LayoutControl Grid.Column="1" Orientation="Vertical" UseLayoutRounding="True" DataContext="{Binding SelectedItem, ElementName=lst1}" Margin="0,10,0,0">
            <dxlc:LayoutGroup Header="{DynamicResource ResourceKey=infogen}" View="GroupBox" Orientation="Vertical" 
                    IsEnabled="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=Window},Path=DataContext.canEditImpianti}" >
                <dxlc:LayoutItem Label="{DynamicResource ResourceKey=Codice}">
                    <dxe:TextEdit EditValue="{Binding CODICE, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" MaxLength="10" MaskType="RegEx" Mask="[0-9A-Za-z]{1,10}" 
                                  NullText="{DynamicResource ResourceKey=obbligatorio}" />
                </dxlc:LayoutItem>
                <dxlc:LayoutItem Label="{DynamicResource ResourceKey=Descrizione}">
                    <dxe:TextEdit EditValue="{Binding NOME, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" MaxLength="20" MaskType="RegEx" Mask="[0-9A-Za-z ]{1,20}" 
                                  NullText="{DynamicResource ResourceKey=obbligatorio}"/>
                </dxlc:LayoutItem>
                <dxlc:LayoutItem Label="{DynamicResource ResourceKey=Citta}">
                    <dxe:TextEdit EditValue="{Binding LOCALITA, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" MaxLength="30"/>
                </dxlc:LayoutItem>
                <dxlc:LayoutItem Label="{DynamicResource ResourceKey=Indirizzo}">
                    <dxe:TextEdit EditValue="{Binding INDIRIZZO, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" MaxLength="30"/>
                </dxlc:LayoutItem>
                <dxlc:LayoutItem Label="{DynamicResource ResourceKey=CAP}">
                    <dxe:TextEdit EditValue="{Binding CAP, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" MaskType="RegEx" Mask="[0-9]{5}"/>
                </dxlc:LayoutItem>
                <dxlc:LayoutItem Label="{DynamicResource ResourceKey=IVA}">
                    <dxe:TextEdit EditValue="{Binding PIVA, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" MaxLength="16"/>
                </dxlc:LayoutItem>
                <dxlc:LayoutItem Label="{DynamicResource ResourceKey=Telefono}">
                    <dxe:TextEdit EditValue="{Binding TELEFONO, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" MaskType="Numeric" MaxLength="18"/>
                </dxlc:LayoutItem>
                <dxlc:LayoutItem Label="{DynamicResource ResourceKey=Responsabile}">
                    <dxe:TextEdit EditValue="{Binding RESPONSABILE, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" MaxLength="20"/>
                </dxlc:LayoutItem>
                <dxlc:LayoutItem Label="E-Mail">
                    <dxe:TextEdit EditValue="{Binding EMAILS, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                                  MaskType="RegEx" Mask="[A-Za-z0-9._%-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}"/>
                </dxlc:LayoutItem>
            </dxlc:LayoutGroup>

            <dxlc:LayoutGroup Header="{DynamicResource ResourceKey=ConfTecnica}" View="GroupBox" Orientation="Vertical"
                              IsEnabled="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=Window},Path=DataContext.canEditImpianti}" >
                <dxlc:LayoutItem Label="{DynamicResource ResourceKey=TipoSistema}">
                    <dxe:ComboBoxEdit IsTextEditable="False" EditValue="{Binding IDTTS, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
                                      ItemsSource="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=Window},Path=DataContext.tts}"  />
                </dxlc:LayoutItem>
                <dxlc:LayoutItem Label="{DynamicResource ResourceKey=Locazione}">
                    <StackPanel Margin="0" Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
                        <RadioButton Content="{DynamicResource Locale}" Margin="10,0,0,0" x:Name="rd_LOCALE" VerticalAlignment="Center"  
                                     IsChecked="{Binding REMOTO,  UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged,Converter={StaticResource InverseBooleanConverter}}" GroupName="LocationL" Panel.ZIndex="9" TabIndex="10" />
                        <RadioButton Content="{DynamicResource Remoto}" Margin="10,0,6,0" x:Name="rd_REMOTO" VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                                     IsChecked="{Binding REMOTO}" GroupName="LocationR" Panel.ZIndex="10" TabIndex="11" Tag="PRISMA"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </dxlc:LayoutItem>
                <dxlc:LayoutItem Label="{DynamicResource ResourceKey=TipoConnessione}">
                    <StackPanel Margin="0" Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                        <RadioButton x:Name="rd_TIPOCONN" Content="{DynamicResource Terminale}" Margin="10,0,0,0" Tag="PRISMA" VerticalAlignment="Center" GroupName="TipoConnT" 
                                     IsChecked="{Binding TIPOCONN, Converter={StaticResource InverseBooleanConverter}, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Panel.ZIndex="11" TabIndex="12" />
                        <RadioButton x:Name="rd_SLAVE" Content="Slave" Margin="10,0,6,0" Tag="PRISMA" VerticalAlignment="Center" GroupName="TipoConnS" 
                                     IsChecked="{Binding TIPOCONN}" Panel.ZIndex="12" TabIndex="13" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </dxlc:LayoutItem>
            </dxlc:LayoutGroup>

            <dxlc:LayoutGroup Header="{DynamicResource ResourceKey=CentralinaSTK}" View="GroupBox" Orientation="Vertical"
                              IsEnabled="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=Window},Path=DataContext.canEditImpianti}" >
                <dxlc:LayoutItem >
                    <StackPanel DockPanel.Dock="Top" Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,6">
                        <RadioButton x:Name="rd_sermatic" Content="{DynamicResource SI}" Margin="10,0,0,0"  Tag="PRISMA" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="100" 
                                     HorizontalAlignment="Left" IsChecked="{Binding SERMATIC, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" GroupName="stkS" Panel.ZIndex="13" TabIndex="14" />
                        <RadioButton x:Name="rd_sermaticNO" Content="{DynamicResource NO}" Margin="10,0,0,0" Tag="PRISMA" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="100" 
                                     HorizontalAlignment="Left" IsChecked="{Binding SERMATIC, Converter={StaticResource InverseBooleanConverter}, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" GroupName="stkN" 
                                     Panel.ZIndex="14" TabIndex="15" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </dxlc:LayoutItem>
                <dxlc:LayoutItem >
                    <!--<dxe:ComboBoxEdit  EditValue="{Binding SERMATICCOM}"/>-->
                    <UniformGrid Rows="1" Columns="2" DockPanel.Dock="Top" Margin="4,0,4,4" IsEnabled="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=rd_sermatic, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
                        <TextBlock Margin="0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{DynamicResource PortaCOM}" TextAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Right"/>
                        <dxe:ComboBoxEdit IsTextEditable="False" EditValue="{Binding SERMATICCOM, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" >
                            <dxe:ComboBoxEdit.Items>
                                <dxe:ComboBoxEditItem Content="COM1"/>
                                <dxe:ComboBoxEditItem Content="COM2"/>
                                <dxe:ComboBoxEditItem Content="COM3"/>
                                <dxe:ComboBoxEditItem Content="COM4"/>
                                <dxe:ComboBoxEditItem Content="COM5"/>
                                <dxe:ComboBoxEditItem Content="COM6"/>
                                <dxe:ComboBoxEditItem Content="COM7"/>
                                <dxe:ComboBoxEditItem Content="COM8"/>
                            </dxe:ComboBoxEdit.Items>
                        </dxe:ComboBoxEdit>
                    </UniformGrid>
                </dxlc:LayoutItem>
            </dxlc:LayoutGroup>
        </dxlc:LayoutControl>
    </Grid>
</ScrollViewer>
```

Comment: Is the `ScrollViewer` inside `dxlc:LayoutControl`? If yes can you not place it around `dxlc:LayoutControl`?

Comment: @dkozl it is already outside, I have update the questin with all the involved xaml.

Comment: I cannot test it with `LayoutControl` but I've just placed big, disabled `DataGrid` within `ScrollViewer` and it scrolls fine. Are you sure that nothing above `ScrollViewer` is also disabled?

Comment: @dkozl yes... I can't do in this way because I need the left part of the grid keeps be active.

Comment: If the scroll viewer is contained within the control you are disabling, it will always be disabled. No way around that. You will have to place your disabled control inside an enabled scroll viewer for it to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have simply disabled the inner layoutGroups. It works.